# How do I scrape specific href's from a site with multiple classes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape https://libraries.io/search?order=desc&platforms=Maven&sort=rank and extract the links to the webpages within the site. When I run the code below I get way too many links from classes I don't need. (I just need the "project" class). How do I pass an argument to just get the links I need?

```
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using css selectors to focus on what you need. Something like

```
for link in soup.select('div.project a[href]'):
    print(link['href']
```

Output:

```
/maven/junit:junit
/maven/org.springframework:spring-context
/maven/org.springframework:spring-test
```

etc.